# PHP returns NULL after sending FormData from React JS (Fetch, method: POST)

Tags: javascript, php, post, fetch

I want to read the content of var in `PHP` when I send data by fetch from React JS (method: POST) and I can see only `null(instead of "szynka")` returned by `$peopleAmount. Console.log()` returns data correctly, but in PHP console log i see this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE3PN.jpg).

App.js

```
    var formData3 = new FormData();
    var szynka = "szynka";
    //var json_params = JSON.stringify(szynka);

    formData3.append('peopleAmount', szynka);

    fetch('http://localhost/api/index.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers : { 
       },
      body: formData3
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
```

**index.php**

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
    $peopleAmount = $_POST['peopleAmount'];
    echo json_encode($peopleAmount);
}
```

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST);` to see what is being sent to the form.

Comment: I see this: https://imgur.com/sWIfboJ

Comment: @dr4 you didn't do what aynber told you to do.

Comment: It looks like for some reason it's not sending the data (shown at the bottom of the image). I don't see anything wrong with your js, but I'm not all that familiar with it. :/